# apache + lighttpd front-proxy concept

Tags: apache, lighttpd

In order to lighten Apache's load people often suggest using lighttpd to serve up static content.

e.g. http://www.linux.com/feature/51673

In this setup Apache passes requests for static content back to lighttpd via mod_proxy, while serving dynamic requests itself.

My question is: how does this reduce the load on the server? Since you still have an apache process spawned for every request that comes in, how does this positively impact the load? From what I can see the size of the Apache process proxying its request through lighttpd is as large as it would be if it were serving the file itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running Lighttpd *behind* Apache to serve static files certainly seems braindead to me. Apache still has to unpack the HTTP packets and parse the request through its parse tree, send proxy requests, and then Lighttpd has to re-unpack, hit the filesystem and send the files back through Apache. I've never heard of anyone using a setup like this in production.

What you will see, is people using a lightweight webserver like [Nginx](http://nginx.net/) as a *frontend* server to serve static files and proxy dynamic URLs to Apache. Or, you can run [Varnish](http://varnish.projects.linpro.no/) or [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) as a caching reverse proxy frontend, so that all your high-traffic static files (i.e. images, CSS etc. *and* any dynamic pages you're willing to send cache-friendly headers for) are served out of memory.

Apache can also be optimized to serve static files -- so often when I hear people complain about Apache, they really don't know how to configure it. They've only ever used the prefork MPM (vs. threaded or worker) and have all sorts of modules enabled (usually they're running from a Linux distribution's kitchen-sink Apache package that builds everything as modules and defaults to enabling 10-20 modules or more). Tune Apache by turning off unneeded modules/stupid features like support for .htaccess (which makes Apache scan the filesystem on every request!) first. (You can also run two instances of Apache, with a "light" Apache as frontend that proxies to a "heavy" Apache for dynamic requests ... maybe your frontend is threaded but your backend is prefork because you have to run thread-unsafe external modules like mod_php.)

Re:

> Since you still have an apache process
>   spawned for every request that comes
>   in, how does this positively impact
>   the load? From what I can see the size
>   of the Apache process proxying its
>   request through lighttpd is as large
>   as it would be if it were serving the
>   file itself.

If you're spawning processes on every request, then that means you're using the prefork MPM. Keep in mind that when the OS reports memory usage for each of these processes, not all that memory is wired, a lot of those processes are idle. And when you're talking about speed, you're concerned more with request parsing and internal code branches for a given request (how much processing is the server doing?) than with memory usage reported by the OS.

For example, if you enable something like mod_php, then each of those worker processes is going to instantly go up by about 20-40M (depending on what's enabled in your PHP interpreter), but that doesn't mean Apache is using that memory on static requests. Of course if you're optimizing your server for maximum concurrency on small static files, then enabling mod_php would still be very bad, you're not going to be able to fit nearly as many prefork processes into RAM.

I probably could come up with a "nightmare configuration" for Apache that *would* make it actually slower serving static files than proxying those requests to a backend Lighttpd, but it would involve enabling expensive features like .htaccess in Apache that are disabled in Lighttpd, so it wouldn't really be fair.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you still have the power *to serve* static and dynamic content from the *same machine* (as they in your [referenced article](http://www.linux.com/feature/51673) do), then I really see no point in that setup.
2. Maybe it does reduce the Load of Apache, because it doesn't have to do IO to the disk, but it will increase the Load of Lighttpd on *the same machine* and thus reducing the *available load to apache* ...
3. Maybe Lighttpd IO access is lighter, than that of Apache 1.3, but why not just switch to Apache 2 or Lighttpd completely? And if the performance really start to suck, host the static files on another machine (media.yourdomain.com).

I small introduction to how you can make a performant setup is found here:
[Deploying Django](http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter20/) -> scroll to `Scaling` some page before the end

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an Apache process spawned for each request - static files (images and the like) are fetched directly by lighttpd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about internal workings of Apache, but one explanation I've seen is about memory pressure.  In short, Apache tries to balance the memory it uses for caching and for dynamic pages; but usually ends up with too much cache and too little for apps.  If you separate them to different processes, each one will optimize for the kind of load.

Currently, what I'm doing is using [nginx](http://nginx.net/) as front end.  It's really fast and light, and specifically designed as a frontend proxy; but also serves static files.  In fact, since it can also call FastCGI processes, you could get rid of Apache and still get the benefits of split file/app processes.  (and there's some extra [memcached magic](http://www.igvita.com/2008/02/11/nginx-and-memcached-a-400-boost/) that looks absolutely genius)

(Yes, lighttpd can also be used as frontend to Apache and/or FastCGI)

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache MPM Worker fastcgi this will lower you server memory usage. MPM worker serves static content better then Prefork and is nearly on par with lighttpd when it comes to static content.

Comment: The CGI Processes will consume the rest of the difference ;)
This won't make the difference at all.